# '... the weather' vs. '... weather'

Tags: definite-articles, uncountable-nouns

There are two correct (I hope so) sentences with *weather* taken from a book:

> - Was *the weather* nice?
> - Did you have nice *weather*?

Can somebody explain why there's an article in the first sentence and there isn't an article in the second one?

Comment: Possible duplicate of some definite article Q.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Issues with articles](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9318/issues-with-articles)

Comment: On second thought, it's not

Comment: Related: [Are there any simple rules for article usage (“a” vs “the” vs none)](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2031/are-there-any-simple-rules-for-article-usage-a-vs-the-vs-none)

Comment: Related: [Should I use a “the” or no article at all?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/22846/should-i-use-a-the-or-no-article-at-all)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Weather is a mass noun. When you ask about the quality of a mass noun using *be*, then it requires the definite article:

> Was the weather nice?
>   Is the milk off?
>   Was the honey sweet?

Asking about *having* a mass noun means you can keep or drop *the*:

> 1. Did you have **the** nice honey?
> 2. Did you have nice honey?

It is important to note that these sentences mean different things. Sentence 1 is asking if, between a selection of honeys, the person had the nice one. Sentence 2 is asking if the honey that the person had was nice, but does not imply that there was a range to try from, that fact is not something you can determine from the question.

When we look at this construction with *weather*

> 1. *Did you have **the** nice weather?
> 2. Did you have nice weather?

Sentence 1 is semantically incorrect because weather is not something you can choose. However, you can modify the question to be, for example, about a previous aspiration and it then requires the definite article:

> 1. Did you have **the** nice weather you were hoping for?
> 2. *Did you have nice weather you were hoping for?

As you can see, this modification makes the second sentence grammatically incorrect, because aspirations require a specific instance to be talked about.

Answer (score 4):

This is not a *weather* phenomenon, that might be what's confusing you.  Consider:

> Was the food delicious?
>   Did you eat delicious food?
>
> Were the beds comfortable?
>   Did you sleep on comfortable beds?
>
> Was the water warm?
>   Did you swim in warm water?
>
> Was the flight bumpy?
>   Did you have a bumpy flight?

The general constructs used here are:

Was [*the*][*noun*][*adjective*]?
Did you [*verb*][*adjective*][*noun*]?

In these constructs, when the noun is a plural noun or a mass noun (e.g., *weather, water, beds*), the article is generally removed.  However, when the noun is singular (such as in last example – *flight*), the article is retained.

Regarding the first example (the one with *food*), change it to *meal* or *meals*, and see how pattern continues:

> Was the meal delicious?
>   Did you eat a delicious meal?
>
> Were the meals delicious?
>   Did you eat delicious meals?

Comment: Does it only apply to questions? e.g, **He was standing in cold weather** vs. **He was standing in a cold weather.** Or, **He usually walks in cold weather vs. He usually walks in a cold weather**. To me the ones with articles sound wrong. What do you think?

Comment: @Noah: Yes, the ones with the articles sound wrong. That's because *weather*, like *food* and *water*, is a plural or mass noun. As I said in my answer: _when the noun is a plural noun or a mass noun (e.g., weather, water, beds), the article is generally removed._

Comment: I noticed 'the' in your example: the ones with **the** articles sound wrong. Is **the necessary**? I didn't use it in my comments. What do you think?

Comment: Noah: Not necessary at all; I could've said, _"the ones with articles sound wrong"_ with no change of meaning in this context.

Answer (score 1):

'the weather' is in reference to how it was at a paticular situation of place and time.

Without the article, it refers to the weather in general.

The first question is about a situation already mentioned earlier in another sentence.

Comment: The second question does not refer to weather in respect of some earlier reference -- it asks if it was nice, which is the focus -- not the situation.

Comment: Remember that the two questions are exactly the same.

Comment: If the questions are exactly the same then they both must refer to some situation that has already been mentioned, which is the case, so your reasoning is flawed.

Comment: The reasoning is fine, indeed. The import of the sentences is different -- not the meaning. Which is what my answer already stated. Hope that encourages a re-read.

Comment: "Without the article, it refers to the weather in general" contradicts itself in the most hilarious way.

Comment: Can you pl share the hilarity?

Comment: @RegDwightΒВBẞ8 it does no such thing.  Kris's answer makes sense, although it could probably have been worded better.  I don't understand why you and Matt are giving him/her such a hard time.

Comment: It doesn't make sense @David, because both questions are probably asking about the same portion of weather, neither is asking about weather in general.

Comment: So Kris's answer is incorrect, and Jasper's comment is on the money.  But it's rather unkind to describe Kris's reasoning as "not making sense", or worse, as "hilarious".  It's just wrong; it's neither nonsensical nor funny.  Just downvote it and move on, or edit it to improve it; but please don't make fun of people here.

Comment: @David I know they didn't mean it's wrong. They imply it should've been 'worded better', as you have  explicitly stated. :-) My answer was intended to be to-the-point.